# Will Apple replace my broken Lightning cable for free?

Tags: warranty, applecare, lightning

I have an iPhone 6 and bought AppleCare for it. The Lightning cable that came with it is starting to split (see the picture). It still charges fine, to the best of my knowledge, but is it eligible for a free replacement under AppleCare?

[image: broken cable]

Comment: I hope so. It will depend on your country of residence, but [contact Apple Support](https://www.apple.com/support/products/) and they will let you know if a replacement is possible.

Comment: Why not, it is a manufacturing defect.

Comment: It's actually a 'treating it too rough' defect. YMMV on whether you'll get them to replace it; whether or not the guy at the counter is in a good mood. My parter can turn any cable into that inside 6 months. I've had them for years without damaging them. I'd recommend [Sugru](https://sugru.com/about) to strengthen the joins (haha, I just spotted it's the very first usage on the site, seems they were listening to me ;)

Comment: If they do so let me know, I have a box of them with the plastic stripped of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had the same situation happen to me with 2 phones actually.  Apple did replace them under warranty.

If you have access to an Apple Store:

- Either walk in or make a Genius Bar appointment
- Be sure to have your iPhone with you
- Apple will need your **IMEI** number from your device

  - To get the **IMEI** number go to **Settings > General > About** (The Apple rep can assist you)

They will then provide you with a new cable after verifying your eligibility.

If you do not have an Apple Store that you can get to, call [AppleCare](https://www.apple.com/support/products/) for instructions.

Answer (score 1):

I have exchanged at least 7 of them in the timespan of 3 years dating back since July 2014, ranging from iPhone 5 to iPhone 6. And in my experience they do it for cables that do not charge anymore since they test that sometimes, but there are times that the person doesn't.

One time they told me that when rips happen, it's not a defect by the cable but more of a misuse by the customer but he still let me replace it since it was the first replacement for my iPhone on file.

They do look for the IMEI from your Apple device to see if it's still under warranty and not the cable's serial number.

You should set up an appointment for the genius bar since sometimes the wait is long.

**Update** for July 4 2017:

I recently went in with my iPhone 7 to replace a lightning cable. I was denied because the cable I brought in had a serial number that did not belong to the iPhone 7. It seems like they are more stringent on the replacements and you have to start tagging which lightning cables belong to which iPhone. My story is similar to this one:
https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/3t47uh/lightning_cable_replacement_policy_changed

Comment: Can verify that at a Apple third party authorised repair shop. This happened to me 1-2 years ago.

Comment: Interesting to know... I've contacted support online and they were always quick to send replacements for frayed cables under warranty with return shipping labels, but I never actually returned the broken ones because I either forgot/was too lazy or wanted to strip the broken cable apart to take a look at the lightning connector (paid for the replacements, ofc)

Answer (score 0):

This is a design flaw of the cable. The phone end is with a sharp profile change resulting in a stress concentration leading to the premature failure. It seems to be an intentional one so that one keeps buying the overpriced cable multiple number of times. I have several Apple devices, all of the cables that came with them have invariably failed. It has nothing to do with the handling as someone in here has said.

Answer (score -3):

if it is a hardware fail they will replace it but if you broke it then they wont do it for free.